# Creating a public intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-menu

So I was trying to make a menu in an application that has a single item. Clicking this menu item takes you to another activity. So basically I'm starting a sub-activity on having that menu item clicked.

The problem is here that I have to specify my intent in the `onCreate()` method of my main activity, but I need this intent in my `onOptionItemSelected()` method which is outside the `onCreate()` method. How do i do this?
My onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   Intent myIntent=new Intent(mainActivity.this,secondActivityt.class);
}
```

My onOptionsItemSelected() method:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   if(item.getItemId()==R.id.aboutbtn){
      startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

So here I'm unable to access `myIntent`. Is there anyway I can declare the intent outside the `onCreate` method and still make the program work, or anyway I can access the intent outside the `onCreate` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be pretty easy, just declare a private class variable and store your intent in that like

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
   private Intent myIntent;

   public void onCreate(...){
      ...
      myIntent = new Intent(...);
   }


   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
      ...
      //use the myIntent here
   }

}
```

I didn't try it out now, but I don't see any reason why this should not work, unless I didn't clearly understand your issue :)

Just as a sidenote. You maybe should also give a look at the Activity lifecycle, basically which event (onCreate, onResume, onStart, onDestroy,...) is fired when. The following figure taken from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) describes it best:
[image]

Comment: :) what I don't understand is what restricts you to create the Intent already in the onCreate, rather than in the `onOptionsItemSelected` directly. The intent you specify above could be easily created directly inside there..

Comment: Yea, i just tried creating the intent in the `onOptionsItemSelected` directly and it did work..and it does make sense...again, I knew its gng to be a lame question...Ive recently started android developing and im a pretty big noob at it...clearly.. :)